# hash-mismatch while running " sudo apt update"

Tags: apt, repository

[image]

**Hash mismatching while running `sudo apt update`**.

```
sudo apt clean && sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
```

both of this command not working it is happening with every mirror evevn from main server

the error message is here :-

```
E: Failed to fetch http://mirror.cse.iitk.ac.in/ubuntu/dists/focal-updates/main/binary-i386/by-hash/SHA256/016259cc5a05a24d9eaa7f7d2e72f00d5f4094c9cae52ab2f6914aa40ae9ec97  Hash Sum mismatch
   Hashes of expected file:
    - Filesize:203432 [weak]
    - SHA256:016259cc5a05a24d9eaa7f7d2e72f00d5f4094c9cae52ab2f6914aa40ae9ec97
    - SHA1:92c84628833d08e7fd4cab4fb6c60f0cb5526908 [weak]
    - MD5Sum:bab37a523ab35365753f89ccb90a0bbb [weak]
   Hashes of received file:
    - SHA256:4c03123d14ede9726beca8dac893b54ef1abf221191a65eaaf40d9a39837d116
    - SHA1:80fbcd190a8038c024e0534c6ee79073d203d73c [weak]
    - MD5Sum:56fe008e11233dda4c8810189b542503 [weak]
    - Filesize:203432 [weak]
   Last modification reported: Thu, 03 Sep 2020 01:14:19 +0000
   Release file created at: Thu, 03 Sep 2020 03:30:39 +0000
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Comment: Problem is still happening even after reinstalling ubuntu 20.04

Comment: Please don't provide pictures of text, we can't copy text from a picture to look up information for you.. and use in response to you.

Comment: Okk , I have added the error message

Answer (score 0):

This problem is sloved by using three command :-

```
sudo apt clean && sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* && sudo apt clean &&  sudo apt update -o Acquire::CompressionTypes::Order::=gz
```